# Why is dim null for lists?

Tags: r, list, lapply

Why is the return of dim null for lists generally?
Also why are vectors not considered 1D matrix,since the result is the same as Null with dim?

Instead of m*n ,why is the dim null in case of lists?

```
numbers<-c(1,2,1,1,2,3,1,1,1)
dim(numbers)<-c(3,3)    
dim( lapply(numbers[1,],sum))
```

> dim( lapply(numbers[1,],sum))
>   NULL
>       Since there are 3 lists,why is it not 3*1 ?

Comment: But what about lists?

Comment: @H1, please post as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

The default `dim()` function returns the `dim` attribute of an object, which needs to be a vector of integer values.  Lists can have `dim` attributes, though they usually don't.  For example,

```
x <- array(as.list(1:10), c(5, 2))
dim(x)
# [1] 5 2
typeof(x)
# [1] "list"
typeof(x[1,1])
# [1] "list"
```

Note that `dim()` is internally a generic function, so you can define S3 methods for it.  For example,

```
x <- structure(1, class = "foobar")
dim.foobar <- function(x) 1:3
dim(x)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

For dataframes, the `dim.data.frame` method is called.

You asked why vectors aren't considered to be 1D matrices.  In R notation, matrices always have 2 dimensions; things with other numbers of dimensions are arrays.  The reason that vectors aren't considered to be 1D arrays is that there's not enough gained from it.  Matrices are vectors with dimension, so if vectors were arrays, you'd have two dimensions to keep track of.

However, when multiplying a matrix times a vector it's useful for vectors to be considered to be either row or column matrices, i.e. arrays with two dimensions where one dimension is 1. R automatically treats vectors in the appropriate way when this is done, following the usual rules from linear algebra.